# $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) and URL Scheme for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, url-scheme

I am having issues with my URL scheme using `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` for two apps.  It doesnt seem to open the correct app when I put in the URL scheme in the browser.  I believe it's only reading the scheme and not the name but I am not sure.  Does the XML below look right for my URL scheme?

The links below do not open the correct app.  com.text.5 URL would open the com.text.0 app.

```
test://com.test.0
test://com.test.5
```

**info.plist**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>test</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` for the scheme also and that seems to fix the issue.  Looks like unlike Android, Apple only uses the scheme to identify the app, not very clever.